# Using Fermat's principle to derive the Cartesian paraboloid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

I am self-studying Optics by Pedrotti and I'm on the subject of geometric optics, specifically ideal Cartesian surfaces. These are reflecting or refracting surfaces that form perfect images. I was able to derive the equation for an ellipsoid using Fermat's principle, but I'm struggling with the algebra for a paraboloid.

[image]

Let point O be object position and origin for the coordinate system. Point O is horizontal distance $f$ from the surface. By Fermat's principle, we must have

$$
|R_1P|+|R_2P|=f+a
$$

or

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+a^2)+y^2}=f+a
$$

Note $a$ is just the distance from $O$ to an arbitrary line that I placed past the rightmost edge of the surface. I think that somehow I should be able to reduce this to $4fy=x^2$, which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_reflector) says is the equation for a parabolic reflector. But.. I'm stuck with the algebra. I just get a mess of terms after squaring a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take $a=0$ without losing generality.

Then I feel like your distance $R_2P$ is wrong.(length measured horizontally)

Finally, the equation of the parabola you indicate assumes $y=0$ at $x=0$: origin at the top of the parabola.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from [@vincent_fraticelli](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/218864/vincent-fraticelli), I was able to figure it out. I modified the coordinate system a bit, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

\begin{align*}
|R_1P|+|R_2P|&=2f+d\\
\sqrt{(f-x)^2+y^2}+d+f-x&=2f+d\\
\sqrt{(f-x)^2+y^2}-x&=f\\
(f-x)^2+y^2&=(f+x)^2
\end{align*}

After some cancellation, I found $y^2 = 4xf$, which is different from the result I mentioned above because my coordinate system is flipped compared to the example in Wikipedia.